# How to build IccLib for 64 bit windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, build, 64-bit

I am trying to build IccLib for x64 bit windows but I am having problems finding any help to do so.

Does anyone have experience with it?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine when I try it.  Be explicit about the problem you are having.

Comment: I was trying to find some more official build for 64 ...
but apparently building the original 32 bit version works fine... couple of warnings but they should be sade

Comment: is there a way to delete question?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to find some more official build for 64 ... but apparently building the original 32 bit version works fine... couple of warnings but they should be safe